# How to save Raw java.lang.Bytes[] to SQLLite BLOB in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have an Array of `java.lang.Bytes[]` in Android and I want to save it to a `SQLLite` table into a BLOB column.

I created the table and columns etc. I am unsure of how to save the Array as a BLOB as is.

```
public void AddUpdateKeys(int deviceID, String key, Boolean learned, Byte[] rawKey)
    {   
    ... // other code
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(colKeyDevID, deviceID);
    cv.put(colKeyLearned, key);
    cv.put(colKeyLearned, learned ? 1 : 0 );        
    cv.put(colKeyData, rawKey); <-- Here is the issue, how to convert Type Byte[] to byte[]
```

How do I convert the Raw data that is in `java.lang.Byte[]` to `byte[]`, I have tried

```
private byte[] getBytes(Byte[] learnedKey) {

    byte[] result = new byte[learnedKey.length];
    for(int i=0; i<learnedKey.length; i++){
        result[i] = learnedKey[i].byteValue();
    }
    return result;
}
```

But is just "crashes", I also checked the the rawKey contains data? I am new to Android `SQLLite` Java. I want to Save the raw data of `Byte[]` into a Blob and read it back later and use it again.

Comment: crashes => post stacktrace.

Comment: Also: why do you have a `Byte[]` in the first place? There's hardly ever a reason to have that *at all*!

Comment: @njzk2: http://pastebin.com/9NVPicJk Log

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: I am getting the Byte[] from a Android NDK C Library

Comment: your log doesn't seem to have anything to do with the posted code.

Comment: I have fixed the error, @Joachim Sauer, I change code to get the NDK code as a byte[].

Comment: @isimobile: Glad to hear that. Posting what you changed (as an answer) could help future visitors who happen to have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

actually An SQL BLOB type stores a large array of binary data (bytes) as the value in a column of a database.
so use column value type should specified as `blob` over `table`.and then save your byte[] into that.you should have to follow these steps over there(exm. image):

1-convert image to bitmap.

2-convert bitmap to Byte array.

```
 public static byte[] getBytesFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (bitmap!=null) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }
    return null;
}
```

3-make column type as blob.
4-save this byte array to that column.